# -wpf canvas events firing only for first time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, commandbinding

I noticed a strange bug. When i bind a command to canvas MouseLeftButtonDown event it does not fire. I tried to debug and noticed that it fires, but only during initialization. I guess the crux is in binding. Here's the code:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Polygons}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas>
                   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <behaviours:MouseBehaviour MouseX="{Binding MouseX, Mode=OneWayToSource}" MouseY="{Binding MouseY, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectPointCommand}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               /* some data template
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And command implementation:

```
 public ICommand SelectPointCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (!CanEdit)
                return new RelayCommand(e => { });

            ClickCounter++;

            if (ClickCounter == 3)
            {
                ClickCounter = 0;
                CanEdit = false;
            }

            return new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    Polygons.Add(new Polygon(ClickedPoints));
                    ClickedPoints.Clear();
                });
        }
    }
```

I guessed problem here is in MouseBehaviour but deleting this piece of code also didnt help.

ps : I tried setting canvas Background property and it didnt work. 
     As well as setting command to this

```
 SelectPointCommand = new RelayCommand(
        () =>
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }, 
        () => true);
```

**EDIT**
I tried to call method like this :

```
 <Canvas Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown">

</Canvas>
```

And the code behind:

```
private void UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       ((MainViewModel)DataContext).SelectPointCommand.Execute(e);
    }
```

Method UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown isn't invoked anyway;
Changing Canvas to StackPanel had same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, i fixed this bug. The problem was here:

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Setting row's Height to "Auto" meant setting it to zero. So canvas just didn't exist! I left it like this :

```
 <RowDefinition/>
```

After that everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to check what is wrong as you don't post all your code. CanEdit property is changed in some other places? What is ClickCounter for?

I think the problem is with getter of SelectPointCommand. It is executed only once, at the moment of creating binding. I would also make use of CanExecute method of ICommand and store returned value of getter in private field. for example:

```
    private ICommand _selectPointCommand;
    ICommand SelectPointCommand
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is executed once");
            return _selectPointCommand;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectPointCommand != value)
            {
                _selectPointCommand = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectPointCommand");
            }
        }
    }
```

In constructor of ViewModel:

```
        SelectPointCommand = new RelayCommand(
                (x) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is executed every click");
                    ClickCounter++;

                    if (ClickCounter == 3)
                    {
                        ClickCounter = 0;
                        CanEdit = false;
                    }
                    Polygons.Add(new Polygon(ClickedPoints));
                    ClickedPoints.Clear();
                },
                (x) => { return CanEdit; });
```

Comment: I tried your fixup, but it still executes only once, unfortunately